# Rails Active Record: How to join three tables?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've three tables as shown below:

[image]

**Advertiser model:**

```
class Advertiser < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :advertisers_account_groups
```

**AdvertisersAccountGroup model**

```
class AdvertisersAccountGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :advertiser
 belongs_to :v2_account_account_group, class_name: 'V2Account::AccountGroup', foreign_key: 'account_group_id'
```

I wanna know which advertiser belongs to `v2_account_account_groups`
 and wanna get `v2_account_account_groups`.name

Desired Output:
[image]

**What I tried;**

```
Advertiser.where(media_type: "line").joins(advertisers_account_groups,v2_account_account_groups)
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: What is the input? Is it a `V2Account::AccountGroup` or `AdvertisersAccountGroup`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that your current setup uses `AdvertisersAccountGroup` as a join table; therefore, I'd suggest using a [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association.

To do this, you'd just need to switch up the models as follows:

```
class Advertiser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :v2_account_account_groups, through: :advertisers_account_groups
  has_many :advertisers_account_groups
  ...
end

class V2Account::AccountGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :advertisers, through: :advertisers_account_groups
  has_many :advertisers_account_groups
  ...
end

class AdvertisersAccountGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :advertiser
  belongs_to :v2_account_account_group, class_name: 'V2Account::AccountGroup', foreign_key: 'account_group_id'
  ...
end
```

This will allow you to query against the `advertiser` as desired, i.e. `advertiser.v2_account_account_groups`.

However, this association is a many-to-many between advertisers and v2 account groups as is - therefore, you won't be able to call `advertiser.v2_account_account_groups.name` as `advertiser.v2_account_account_groups` returns a collection rather than a single record.

You could use `advertiser.v2_account_account_groups.map(&:name)` (to get an array of all groups' names) or `advertiser.v2_account_account_groups.first&.name`, but it sounds as if you might need to restructure the data if an advertiser should have just the one v2 account group.

Does that make sense and sound like what you're looking for? Let me know if you've any questions.

---

Edit:

Based on your comment, I think you should be able to construct a query as follows:

```
Advertiser.includes(advertiser_account_groups: : v2_account_account_group)
          .where(advertiser_account_groups: { v2_account_groups: { name: "something" } })
```

Does that sound like what you're looking for?

A couple of things to note:

- when referencing the associations in the `includes`, you want to use the association name
- *however*, when plugging these into the `where` clause, you need to use the full table names, as they are in the databases (searchable via `Model.table_name`)

Also, in your comment, you reference adding `media_type: "line"`, which the below also includes:

```
Advertiser.includes(advertiser_account_groups: : v2_account_account_group)
          .where(media_type: "line", advertiser_account_groups: { v2_account_account_groups: { name: "something" } })
```

Probably the best way to structure this in your code is as a scope in your advertiser model, such as:

```
scope :by_v2_group_name, -> (name) { includes(advertiser_account_groups: :v2_account_account_group)
                               .where(media_type: "line", advertiser_account_groups: { v2_account_account_groups: { name: "something" } }) }
```

or

```
scope :by_v2_group_name, (lambda do |name| 
  includes(advertiser_account_groups: :v2_account_account_group)
  .where(media_type: "line", advertiser_account_groups: { v2_account_account_groups: { name: "something" } })
end)
```

That will then allow you to keep your code clean and call `Advertiser.by_v2_group_name("something")`.

Let me know how you get on with that and we'll work on it as needed :)

Comment: Thanks but I don't wanna change the code. I just want to write a Active recode query to find which advertiser belongs to which v2_account_groups. An advertiser can belong to multiple `v2_account_groups`.  For ex- I want to write Advertiser.where(media_type: "line").joins(:v2_account_account_groups).where("something")

Comment: Thanks @RajSharma - I've expanded my answer to reflect this. Hope it helps - if you've any questions or it doesn't work anywhere (I've not been able to test it), give me a shout and we'll see what we can figure out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me.

Answer (score -1):

**This answer is relevant only if you don't need a *model* for the join table 
 advertiser_account_gourps**
(if you don't have any extra attributes other then `advertiser_id` and `account_gourp_id` on that join table - you usually don't need it)

While @SRack's answer is using the `has_many :through` association, I think you can use a simple many-to-many association (`has_and_belongs_to_many`) because in your images i can see that the join table only have the `ids` of the associated tables (Unless you do need the `id` column -> and in that case, use @SRack's solution!)

```
class Advertiser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :advertisers_account_groups

class AccountGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :advertisers
```

then you can get them using:

```
advertiser = Advertiser.first
advertiser.account_groups #to get account groups of that advertiser
```

and vice versa:

```
account_group = AccountGroup.first
account_group.advertisers # to get advertisers of that account group
```

- @SRack's comment is correct! i changed it to HABTM association!

In that case you will need to create a migration to make the join table:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableAdvertiserAccountGroup advertiser account_group
```

This table will only include the associated `advertiser_id` and the `account_group_id`.

You don't need to create a model and handle stuff on that table, rails will fill that table for you.

Comment: I went `has_many :through` as he's got an `id` column on `advertisers_account_group` and he'd need to nuke that column to use a many-to-many. I _always_ prefer a `has_many :through` association, as has pretty much everything I've read on the subject / people I've worked with (though happy to hear others' opinions here!). Plus wouldn't yours need to be a `has_and_belongs_to_many` anyway? And no mention of the v2 groups?

Comment: @SRack: you right in this case. habtm needed to make many to many relationship in this case.

Comment: @SRack yup, you are correct about that `habtm`. I just posted another way to do what he wants, i guess that the `id` in his `advertiser_account_group` is not really needed....

Comment: But habtm doesn't work with an `id` column on the join table... IMO seems more work than it's worth killing the column when you can use `has_many :through` :) Plus you've then got the flex to use the join table as needed.

Comment: I know that it doesn't have that `id` column .... i edited my answer and specified that if he need that `id` column he should use your answer...

Comment: Cool cool - maybe add info on dropping the `id` column in that case?